# Sort Orders by Customer Groups in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I have to Sort order by Customer Groups in magento 1.7.0.2, I try to follow magento wiki:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/sort_order_by_customer_groups

But it doesn't works.

I copy app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to not touch magento core.

I add this code to this function

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){

 $this->addColumn('customer_group_id', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Group'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'group_id',
                'renderer' => new   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_CustomerGroup(),
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_CustomerGroup::getCustomerGroupsArray(),
        ));

// now the code original
}
```

Second, in the same file I add this override function

```
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column) {

        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            $field = ( $column->getFilterIndex() ) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
            if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
                call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
            }
            else {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                    if (in_array('NULL', array_values($cond))) {
                        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, array('null' => true));
                    }
                    else {                      
                        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

third, in the Grid.php I modify this function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
          array('ce'=>'customer_entity'),
          'ce.entity_id=main_table.customer_id',
          array('ce.group_id')
        );
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Now I create this file in app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/CustomerGroup.php with this code:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_CustomerGroup
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

    // Holds an associative array with customer_group_id and the associated label
    private static $_customerGroups = array(); // "singleton"

    public static function getCustomerGroupsArray() {
        // Make sure the static property is only populated once
        if (count(self::$_customerGroups) == 0) {
            $customer_group = new Mage_Customer_Model_Group();
            $customer_groups = $customer_group->getCollection()->toOptionHash();
            self::$_customerGroups = $customer_groups;
        }

        return self::$_customerGroups;
    }

    // Transforms the customer_group_id into corresponding label
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $val = $this->_getValue($row);
        $customer_groups = self::getCustomerGroupsArray();
        return isset($customer_groups[$val]) ? $customer_groups[$val] : false;
    }

}
```

And I have this error:

**:5:{i:0;s:92:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_group_id' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:5645:"#0 MyProjectFolder\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try replacing customer_group_id by group_id in your first code to fit column name, or add an alias

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in magento forum, someone gives me the right solution:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->join(
          array('oe'=>'sales_flat_order'),
          'oe.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
          array('oe.customer_group_id')
        );
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```